# Prove that any rational number can be represented as the square difference of two rational numbers

Tags: rational-numbers

This proposition was proposed by my deskmate. And I gave a method to work out it.

So I want to communicate with masters of mathematics here.

This is my proof process:

"For $p\in \mathbb{Q}$, choose $k\in \mathbb{Q}$ (and $k \neq 0$)

construct $m, n$ like:

$m$ = $\frac{k^2+p}{2k}$

$n$ = $\frac{k^2-p}{2k}$

And $m^2-n^2$ = $(m+n)(m-n)$ = $p$."

Comment: Seems needlessly complex...and we only need one example, not a family.  If we look at the system $m+n=p$, $m-n=1$ we get $m=\frac {p+1}2$ and $n=\frac {p-1}2$.  That works.

Comment: Thank you very much，I used this complex method because my deskmate need a formula to study the universal sense.(by the way, my deskmate'name is chaochao)

Comment: Well, your formula does give a family of solutions, though you ought to specify $k\neq 0$.  Looking at the expressions, we easily get $m+n=k, m-n=\frac pk$.

Comment: Sorry very much.I am changing it now .And your equation is also where my inspiration comes from.